# How can I make __str__ or __repr__ return the current class's name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, python-class

I have this code:

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, pay, gender):
        self.name = name
        self.pay = pay
        self.gender = gender

    def add_raise(self):
        self.pay = int(self.pay*1.10)

    def __str__(self):
        if self.gender == "Female" or self.gender == "female":
            return f"{__class__.__name__} name: {self.name}, and she earns {self.pay} Pound"
        else:
            return f"{__class__.__name__} name: {self.name}, and he earns {self.pay} Pound"

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.gender == "Female" or self.gender == "female":
            return f"{__class__.__name__} name: {self.name}, and she earns {self.pay} Pound"
        else:
            return f"{__class__.__name__} name: {self.name}, and he earns {self.pay} Pound"

class Supervisor(Employee):
    def __init__(self, name, pay, gender, department):
        super().__init__(name, pay, gender)
        self.department = department
```

Now, when I try to run

```
emp1 = Employee("Ron", 1000, "male")
emp10 = Supervisor("Hermoine", 3000, "female", "General")
print(emp1, emp10)
```

I only get "Employee name" at the beginning. How do I change it so it reflects that "Hermoine" is a `Supervisor` and not just an `Employee`, without re-writing both the `__str__` and `__repr__` methods?

Comment: Honestly, I'd make the "role" explicit in an instance attribute, rather than trying to reuse the class name. Add `self.role = "Employee` or `self.role = "Supervisor"` in the appropriate `__init__` methods.

Comment: (Or a class attribute, `role = "Employee"` directly in the `class` statement namespace.)

Comment: @chepner, the `self.__class__.__name__` approach suggested by @U12-Forward is a pretty common pattern for `__repr__` methods. See, for example,  `collections.OrderedDict`, `collections.Counter`, `collections.namedtuple` and `collections.ChainMap`. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/collections/__init__.py

Comment: It's not one that I like, especially for `str`. It's fine for `repr`, which is only intended as a debugging tool anyway. For `__str__`, I'd rather use explicit data rather than a value inferred from *code*.

Comment: Well, fair enough — but I think it's useful to note that it's arguably the norm in the standard library to define `__repr__` methods like this, and to leave `__str__` undefined (meaning that calls to `__str__` will fall back to the `__repr__` method). I'm also not entirely sure why you don't consider the class name to be explicit data — it's very rare that you're dynamically setting or modifying a class name at runtime.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Solution:

Try changing your first class to:

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, pay, gender):
        self.name = name
        self.pay = pay
        self.gender = gender

    def add_raise(self):
        self.pay = int(self.pay*1.10)

    def __str__(self):
        if self.gender == "Female" or self.gender == "female":
            return f"{self.__class__.__name__} name: {self.name}, and she earns {self.pay} Pound"
        else:
            return f"{self.__class__.__name__} name: {self.name}, and he earns {self.pay} Pound"

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.gender == "Female" or self.gender == "female":
            return f"{self.__class__.__name__} name: {self.name}, and she earns {self.pay} Pound"
        else:
            return f"{self.__class__.__name__} name: {self.name}, and he earns {self.pay} Pound"
```

Try `self.__class__.__name__` instead of `__class__.__name__` in all strings.

And now:

```
emp1 = Employee("Ron", 1000, "male")
emp10 = Supervisor("Hermoine", 3000, "female", "General")
print(emp1, emp10)
```

Output:

```
Employee name: Ron, and he earns 1000 Pound Supervisor name: Hermoine, and she earns 3000 Pound
```

## Explanation:

The reason why `self` returns the actual class name is because it will extract the class name from the current `self` instance. Without `self` would only get the class name of the original parent class, not the actual class it's currently in, that's the reason `self` is so important.

Also as @MadPhysicist mentioned, it's "because `__class__` is lexically scoped at class execution time".

Comment: Because `__class__` is lexically scooped at class execution time: i.e., it's a hard coded `Emplpyee` reference

Comment: @MadPhysicist Ah yeah! added it into my answer, thanks for the suggestion!